# Prevent Solr from creating default copy fields

Tags: solr, solrcloud

When I add any field in Solr and then index some data, Solr creates a copy field for this field.

For example I added a field named `app_id` and after indexing there are data both in  `app_id` and another field named `app_id_str`.

Is there any way to prevent creating these copy fields ?

Comment: In addition to the answers by Kusal and Eric I would note that if you define the field in your schema ahead of time (e.g. add `app_id' as a string field to your schema) then Solr will not automatically create the `_str` field. Solr only creates those fields for dynamically created fields.

Answer (score 4):

**Schema.xml**

Search for `copyField` definitions using wildcards in their glob pattern in *schema.xml*.

> The copyField command can use a wildcard (*) character in the dest
>   parameter only if the source parameter contains one as well. copyField
>   uses the matching glob from the source field for the dest field name
>   into which the source content is copied.

You need to comment anything that looks like this :

```
<copyField source="*" dest="*_str"/>
```

You may also have some `dynamicField` definitions like the following that would create any copied fields (otherwise you would perhaps remember having explicitly defined such fields like `app_id_str`) :

```
<dynamicField name="*_str" type="string"/>
```

---

**SchemaLess Mode**

> Internally, the Schema API and the Schemaless Update Processors both
>   use the same Managed Schema functionality.

If you are using Solr in "schemaless mode", you can do the same either by using the Schema API :

- [Delete a Copy Field Rule](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/schema-api.html#delete-a-copy-field-rule)
- [Delete a Dynamic Field Rule](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/schema-api.html#delete-a-dynamic-field-rule)

Or by reconfiguring the dedicated update processor in *solrconfig.xml* as stated by Kusal.

See the paragraph titled *You Can Still Be Explicit* below [this section](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/schemaless-mode.html#examples-of-indexed-documents).

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you are using a reasonably new Solr version. (I do not have enough reputation to comment on the problem yet) You can prevent Solr from automatically creating copy fields during index time. You just have to configure the "add-schema-fields" update processor not to create copy fields on the fly. Here is how,

1. Open the solrconfig.xml file of the core you wish to disable adding copy fields automatically.
2. Comment out the configuration to disable the copy field creation on text fields (or any type of field that is configured to generate a copy field).

[image]

3. Save and restart the Solr instance.
4. Index the documents.